# Clojure postgresql: how do I drop the database?

Tags: postgresql, clojure

Using clojure and clojure-sql with postgresql.

I am trying to make a bootstrap function, so I want to drop all the tables in the db and then rebuild them cleanly.  As there are an arbitrary number of tables it would be nice if I could just drop them all at once.  However, this fails:

```
(def db
  {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
   :subprotocol "postgresql"
   :subname "//localhost/triface"
   :user "postgres"})

(defn rebuild-table []
  (sql/with-connection db
    (sql/do-commands "drop database triface" "create database triface")))
```

How do I issue a drop database command from a somehow modified connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out from another question over here: [How do I drop or create a database from clojure.java.jdbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832968/how-do-i-drop-or-create-a-database-from-clojure-java-jdbc) .

Finally!

Answer (score 0):

You can't drop the Database you're connected to. Connect to another database (e.g. `template1`) before issuing the drop/create commands.

Comment: That's a good question!  Trying to figure that out over here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074327/clojure-postgresql-how-do-i-see-the-exception-when-an-error-is-in-the-db

Comment: Alright, got it finally: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: DROP DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Comment: Seems like `do-commands` runs the commands inside a transaction (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.sql/do-commands). You'll have to issue the commands individually with some other mechanism than `do-commands`.

Comment: It seems the transaction is not an option.  Going through the docs it seems that do-commands is the most general mechanism clojure.contrib.sql provides for interacting with the database.  How do I execute a command from clojure without a transaction?

Comment: I don't know Clujure, but could you do `sql/do-commands "rollback" "drop database triface" "create database triface" "begin"`? This should cancel the transaction started by do-commands, but restore a transaction state so that the automatic commit will not trigger an error.